# How to pass Description of downstream job to upstream job in Jenkins MultiJob

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We've job to run concurrent jobs in parallel using Jenkins [MultiJob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) . We are using [Description Setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin) to update the description for failed jobs in all downstream and upstream jobs. How can I update the description of Upstream job with reason of failure in the downstream job.

[image]

Is there any way to get the Description from downstream job to Upstream job using a plugin or a groovy script? Can somebody help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a description URL for each of your jobs. You could have your downstream jobs POST form data with a "description" parameter to set the description.

I found this info under (jenkins server)/job/(job)/api/

[Fetch/Update job description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a0fj.jpg)

Comment: It will update the whole job description and not a specific build

Answer (score 0):

You can use Groovy Postbuild plugin to execute groovy script after the downstream job gets done. The advantage of the groovy script that it gives you access to Jenkins environment, you can access any data from anywhere as far as I know (but not so sure about it).
Execute the the script bellow, it should work. Handle exception, if needed.

```
def build_number= 12
def job = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem("upstream_job")
def upstream_build = job.builds.find {it.number == build_number}
upstream_build.description = "New description"
```